# Nested routes with lazy-loaded modules

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an application were I have a couple of modules that can work independently but in some cases, I want to display a component from one of the other modules.

Lets say, module 1 is my "Files module" and module 2 is my "Folders module". One folder can exist by its own (no files related), but some folders can have related files and the user can choose to view those file details without leaving the Folder view.

Here is an example application, where you can see the behavior im looking for but i've set the routes without lazy-loading: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kjy3xl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodule2%2Flist%2Flist.component.html

For the example I hardcoded the routes, but the Idea is to have them being dynamically built, setting the corresponding outlet name.

I've tried to lazy-load the modules like you can see in the file module1-routing.module :

```
// Expected
const MODULE1_ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./module1-detail-routing.module').then(
        (m) => m.Module1DetailRoutingModule
      ),
  },
];

//in module1-detail-routing.module
const MODULE1_DETAIL_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: DetailComponent,
    outlet: 'lvl1',
  },
  {
    path: 'module2',
    outlet: 'lvl1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../module2/module2-routing.module').then(
        (m) => m.Module2RoutingModule
      ),
  },
];
```

But then I am not able to set the outlet for the routes in module2 depending on what "level" the route is. In that example it should be outlet:'lvl2'.

TL;DR; How can I change the routes when lazy-loading a module so I can dynamically set their "outlet"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. In the example you have provided, the author tries to set outlet's name as a property (`<router-outlet [name]="nextOutlet"></router-outlet>`) which is not possible by design: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#description

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy I think what the documentation is referring to is changing it after the DOM has been rendered.
From the example, you can see that in the DOM, the outlets are being rendered with the correct name:
```<router-outlet _ngcontent-ng-c3656479608="" ng-reflect-name="lvl1"></router-outlet>```.

The reason this was done is so you can have the same component rendering an outlet that depends on the parent outlet.

Example: If the component is in outlet 'lvl1' then the component should render an outlet with name 'lvl2'

Comment: No, the docs are correct: names were hardcoded in HTML because this is a bit more than just what you see as HTML in your dev console. The property *was* an attribute because property binding happens later than routing routine needed. But as I said, it *was* because it looks like an Angular team pushed a change that converted `name` to input property https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c3f857975d56cac6ad3939d64f76a51455159c23 I was not aware of it. But what exactly are you trying to achieve? Having two outlets seems to be enough, it is just a question of routing config.

Comment: can you please write the sequence of steps, the actual and the expected result?